# Categorizing R Corpuses using NLTK and SKLEARN

Tags: python, r, classification, document

I have a set of documents that have been cleaned in R using the tm package. Ultimately they were converted to a dataframe and saved as .txt files using the write.table function.

I then wrote python code using sklearn and ntlk to classify these documents using a pipeline with a Naive Bayes Classifier (this isn't important) and to dump the predicted outcomes into data frame. The classification works. However, when I recover the predicted labels and the predicted probabilities (using sklearn.pred_proba), I get 2 sets of probabilities for each document. The reason I believe this is happening is because the files that were processed in R have a "doc_id" associated with them, and I believe that the Python classification code I wrote tries to classify the text in the "doc_id" as well as the actual text in the file, so that instead of an ndarray with dimensions [1,3] when classifying a single document into the 3 categories I recover an ndarray with dimensions [2,3]. I have read the documentation on tm, sklearn, and ntlk, and I have read all of the stack exchange blogposts that came up under my search terms, but I cannot figure out how to either:

1) remove the doc_id from the R files
2) have sklearn model.predict and model.predict_proba classify only the text and not the doc_id.

Any help you could offer would be great. This seems like it should be an easy fix, but none of the solutions I have tried so far have fixed it, including using the CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader function in python to extract the raw text using reader.raw because the model.predict function won't accept a series of strings, which is the object reader.raw produces.

My python code that might be useful:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformerCleaned_For_Classification_USStateDepartment_Volumes
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('file', r'file_.*\.txt', cat_pattern =r'file_(\w+)\.txt')
liberaltext = reader.raw(fileids='file_liberal.txt')
realisttext = reader.raw(fileids='file_realist.txt')
atheoretictext = reader.raw(fileids='file_atheoretic.txt')
documents = [liberaltext, realisttext, atheoretictext]
categories= ['liberal','realist', 'neither']
listofpredprobs = pd.DataFrame({"liberal": [0], "realist": [0], "neither":[0]})

def stemming_tokenizer(text):
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    return [stemmer.stem(w) for w in word_tokenize(text)]

model = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=stemming_tokenizer, stop_words = stopwords.words('english'), encoding=u'UTF-8'), MultinomialNB())
model.fit(documents, categories)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('file'):
    for file in files:
        test = open(os.path.join("file", file), 'r')
        labels = model.predict(test)
        test = open(os.path.join("file", file), 'r')
        predprobs = model.predict_proba(test)
        dfpp = pd.DataFrame(predprobs, columns=categories)
        listofpredprobs = listofpredprobs.append(dfpp)
```

Comment: When you read in data to your data-frames, you should be able to select exactly the columns you want, why can't you just do that? Also, there's a lot going on in your code, maybe try to remove extraneous stuff? Check out how to make an [mcve]. You could provide a small example, maybe, of text, instead of providing a bunch of code that walks through a directory... something we could actually *run* to see the type of results you are seeing.

Comment: As a complete aside, I've had a go at formatting your code a bit to make it more readable for most people working with Python. Unless you need to use otherwise, see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for guidance on formatting (I didn't go all the way, but to make it legible). Beforehand all I saw was a wall of text; it'll help you in any future coding project.

Comment: As an aside, you *really* don't want to be using a `pd.DataFrame` for your `listofpredprobs` and then `.append`ing to it. If the number of files is small, it won't be a big issue, but this will scale horrifically. You should just use a regular python list, `[]`, which has *excellent* `.append` efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for the comments on the code. When I tried to simply "extract the column I want" I get the error code: TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: I have about 700 documents to classify, so the dataframe  appending works fine. I tried simply appending to a list at first, but when the ndarrays have 3 dimensions, this makes for a mess of an object to unravel. If I can figure out how to stop it from classifying the doc_id, I can simply append in list form.

Comment: What do these files look like? `TfidfVectorizer` just takes a sequence of strings. You could probably just parse your text-files instead of using `CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader`, which I've never seen much of a need for.

Comment: The files are just line of words separated by white space: 
or assez assidu assign assissin assist assistanceÃ assiz associ associationÃ assoupi assuag assum assumpt assur asta astano astir astonish astor astound astut asund asylum athen athenaeum athenaum athenÃ athlet athlÃ atkinson atlant atlanticÃ atlas atom aton atroc atroci atrocityÃ attach attack attah attain atteignai atteignait attemp attempt attemptÃ attend attendanceth attent attentionÃ atterÃ attest attila

Answer (score 0):

Well, to solve it, I ended up re-processing the docs to classify using python. That did the trick! It took a couple of hours to process them all, but its done now. Thanks for your help.